# to create a generic function subscribing to observable

Tags: angular, callback, subscribe, unsubscribe

I have serveral observables needed to be subscribed when a component instantiated. I do not want to subscribe each observables with duplicate code, so I created the function (testMethod).

```
testMethod<T>(observable: Observable<T>, cb, cbe) {
    observable.subscribe((d: T) => { cb(d); }, (error) => { cbe(); });
}

subscribeObservables() {
    this.testMethod(this.store.aObservable$, a, ae));
    this.testMethod(this.store.bObservable$, b, be)); 
    this.testMethod(this.store.cObservable$, c, ce)); 
}
```

I think it is efficient because it eliminates code duplication considerably. But it is a little ambiguous to unsubscribe. And I do not know this has correct rational and has negative effects. Could someone give some advice for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve just the same using the following `this.store.cObservable.subscribe(cb)`

Comment: if I have only one callback, i would be okay, but there must be more callbacks for it. i do not want to duplicate them so...